# Why can't I import parametrize from pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I know there is `parametrize` decorator in `pytest`, e.g.:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("num1, num2", [(1, 1)])
def test_equal(num1, num2):
    assert num1 == num2
```

However, I wonder why can't I import `parametrize` decorator directly, i.e. if I write `from pytest.mark import parametrize` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest.mark'`.

Why I can call `pytest.mark.parametrize` but cannot call `from pytest.mark import parametrize`?

**P.S.:** It's not a question about a proper usage, I'm perfectly fine using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`. It's rather about comprehension of the import process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest.mark'` is telling you that `pytest.mark` isn't a module. You can use `pytest.mark` because that's an object that exists, but you can't `import pytest.mark`. Just like you can use `pytest.raises` but can't `import pytest.raises`, nor can you `import math.sin`.